# Only first 2 controls get Click event assigned in tableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a table as seen on the left in this picture
[image]
I populate it using the following

```
private void populateQuestionTable()
    {
        answerTable.Controls.Add(new Button() { Text = "1", Font = new Font("Arial", 12) }, 0, 0);
        answerTable.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "A", Font = new Font("Arial", 12) }, 1, 0);
        answerTable.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "B", Font = new Font("Arial", 12) }, 2, 0);
        answerTable.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "C", Font = new Font("Arial", 12) }, 3, 0);
        answerTable.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "D", Font = new Font("Arial", 12) }, 4, 0);
        answerTable.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "E", Font = new Font("Arial", 12) }, 5, 0);
        for( int i = 1; i < 50; i++ )
        {
            answerTable.RowCount = answerTable.RowCount + 1;
            answerTable.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 40));

            answerTable.Controls.Add(new Button() { Text = Convert.ToString(i + 1), Font = new Font("Arial", 12) }, 0, i);
            answerTable.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "A", Font = new Font("Arial", 12) }, 1, i);
            answerTable.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "B", Font = new Font("Arial", 12) }, 2, i);
            answerTable.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "C", Font = new Font("Arial", 12) }, 3, i);
            answerTable.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "D", Font = new Font("Arial", 12) }, 4, i);
            answerTable.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "E", Font = new Font("Arial", 12) }, 5, i);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            (answerTable.GetControlFromPosition(0, i) as Button).Click += showQuestion;
    }
```

Yet only the first and second button will fire the Click event when actually clicked.
I'm kind of new to C#, so my knowledge of this might be limited. Is there a limit to what number of controls might have a function assigned to them?
If not, then what is wrong with the code I wrote?

Comment: Your second for loop does not seem right. It seems like you are missing a set of curly brackets ({}). Also, why you iterate from _0 to 50_, where as in your first loop you iterate from _1 to 50_?

Comment: @Eminem I don't add the first row to the table, only following. If it doesn't seem right, could you explain why? It's using the correct collumn and row, as far as I'm aware, it just doesn't seem to register for anything besides the first and second row.

Comment: It looks ok at first glance. put the cursor on the `showQuestion`, right-click and chose breakpoint-add . The run F5 and check how often you hit the registering..

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong. Have you stepped through to see what buttons are returned by `GetControlForPosition`? You should be able to check the `Text` property.

Comment: @CharlesMager They all return correct values, up to 50.

Comment: @TaW What do you mean by registering? I had to press the F5 key a lot for it to go through that loop, so it seems like it's assigning everything...

Comment: Indeed. sorry, I just meant: try if it gets hit more then 2 times ;-) - So the culprit could be the showQuestion() method.. Does it never get hit from the lower buttons or does it not work? You'll have to show us in the latter case..!  (Registering the event is what the `click+=..` does )

Comment: I've pasted your code into a new project and every button works fine, so sadly your code isn't enough to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Yes, I can confirmCharles comment. Your code works fine. Except for one thing: You __need__ to add a `answerTable.SuspendLayout();` to the start and an `answerTable.ResumeLayout();` to the end of the `populateQuestionTable` method or else it will take __several__ seconds to set up the buttons etc.. -  You probably have checks in the showAnswer routine that go wrong..